# Does bundle.putByteArray copy the whole buffer or pass the pointer in Android?

Tags: android, bundle, message

I have to pass a buffer from one thread to another and I am using bundle.putByteArray (String key, byte[] value) method to do that. My question whether this method copies the whole buffer to another buffer and passes it or just sends the pointer to the array?

If it is copying the whole buffer, I need to avoid this function call as it will be expensive. Please clarify my doubt.

Thanks,
Shamy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Bundle.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java), all it does is insert your key value pair in a standard HashMap.  So no, it's not doing a copy.